# How many ways can a committee of six be made from 4 students and 8 teachers if the committee contains at least three students?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can a committee of six be made from 4 students and 8 teachers if the committee contains **at least three students**?

The obvious answer would be to select 3 students and 3 teachers or 4 students and 2 teachers, which is $${4 \choose 3}{8 \choose 3} + {4 \choose 4}{8 \choose 2} = 252$$ which corresponds to the given answer.

**However, my first approach at the problem was a bit different and I don't see why it is wrong:** First select 3 students, so that the condition of at least 3 students is satisfied, then choose any 3 out of the remaining 9 people (8 teachers + 1 student). $${4 \choose 3}{9 \choose 3} = 336 \neq 252$$

So why is this method incorrect?

Comment: You counted, for example, choosing students A, B, C "first" and D later as different from choosing A, B, D and C later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fist approach, you are counting same things twice.

Say students are $A,B,C,D$. Now first choosing $A,B,C$ and then among the remaining nine choosing $D$ and two teachers is same as choosing $A,B,D$ and then choosing $C$ and the same two teachers but these two are counted twice in your approach.

Did I make it clear?

Comment: Ahh, i get it. Thank you both!

Comment: Notice that Tony's first approach counts each selection of all four students four times, once each for each way of selecting three of them.  Therefore, $$\binom{4}{3}\binom{9}{3} = \binom{4}{3}\binom{8}{3} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{4}\binom{8}{2}$$

Comment: @N.F.TaussigYes...that is good of you to notice...I missed that.